# W3C validation Illegal character in query: not a URL code point

Tags: html, w3c-validation

The w3C validator has found an error in my HTML:

> Bad value comment_add.php?id= 7 for attribute action on element form: Illegal character in query: not a URL code point.

It marked the closing ">" tag as a problem

```
<form method="post" action="comment_add.php?id= 7"**>**
```

The code which generated that HTML is:

```
<form method="post" action="comment_add.php?id=<?= $id_post;?>">
```

I have a few other lines with the same issue.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There should not be any spaces in the action of the form.

You should change your code to:

```
<form method="post" action="comment_add.php?id=<?=$id_post;?>">
```

If you need a space in your URL is should be encoded as `%20`. So the code would then look like:

```
<form method="post" action="comment_add.php?id=%20<?=$id_post;?>">
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to have any effect but i have just noticed that this problem only applies to $id_post numbers under 10. It automatically puts a blank character before the number.

Comment: What is the data type of $id_post? If it is a string you can use [trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) to remove leading spaces.

Comment: Ok, now I can see my error, the $id_post had a blank space because on the main page there was still a blank space in my code, therefore all the other code carried that blank space afterwards, so your solution is absolutely correct! Thank you!